# Commerce Add-On + FoxyCart?

Tags: ecommerce

**Instead of developing something from scratch is there any existing commerce kind of add-on that could speed up integrating FoxyCart and members?** There are no products, codes, categories, or anything else in my EE yet so how that gets put into EE can be completely subjective at this point, too. I haven't really touched anything asides from the Simple Commerce Module in EE 1.6.x.

For those of you not familiar with [FoxyCart](http://www.foxycart.com/) it basically does not assume anything about your e-commerce, it doesn't hold products, but it does create customers invisibly on its end (you can use their API/DataFeed to communicate from your end and/or to receive updates on their end). It keeps track of transactions and can make recurring subscriptions regardless of your merchant gateway. You provide FoxyCart with all the information based on your cart/checkout, such as products, discounts, coupons, categories, you make it all up (can be done securely so the data can be determined to not have been tinkered with) and FoxyCart will present your user with a cart, checkout, etc. It's completely open-ended so you can make your own user experience as you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would look at creating your own option. I have done it in the past with just custom fields and building out the product links like they have in the FoxyCart docs or you could build a module if you are comfortable with PHP. I was in the [acmecart.com](http://acmecart.com) (the new modules name from HCC) beta since late 2010 and have not received an updated build in at least a year (I might not be on their list anymore for new beta releases but I just dont know)

Answer (score 4):

You could look at [FoxEE by HCC Development](http://www.hccdevelopment.com/Web-Based-Software/Product/foxee/) ... though they've been quiet as of late, poking around their forum it looks like they [might have an update about to ship](http://www.hccdevelopment.com/Web-Based-Software/Support-Forums/viewthread/1173/#4547).

Comment: Good to know it's not dead, but also going by their forums they've been saying similar things since 2009. Need something ASAP so no definitive dates whatsoever for years is unreliable to say the least. Can't seem to register on their forums so I shot them an email. Thanks Derek.

Comment: Personally I would look at creating your own option. I have done it in the past with just custom fields and building out the product links like they have in the FoxyCart docs or you could build a module if you are comfortable with PHP. I was in the http://acmecart.com (the new modules name from HCC) beta since late 2010 and have not received an updated build in at least a year (I might not be on their list anymore for new beta releases but I just dont know).

Comment: Yeah right now I'm storyboarding user experiences and trying to figure out how FoxyCart stuff would map to EE stuff, all my content & business logic needs. FoxyCart is straight forward enough, but product grouping, member orders/account management, the desired/needed features are escalating. HCC hasn't gotten back to me either, in all likelihood I will end up just stacking add-ons and developing the rest. As you said a FoxyCart product itself may as well just be an entry with given fields and one enumerating one for custom fields. Thanks @JustinLong. I'll give this question a little more time.

Comment: @JustinLong Would you mind re-submitting your comment as an answer so I can mark this as answered?